# Let A and B are matrices such that all eigenvalues ​​have negative real part. Flows of the systems $X ' = AX$ and $X ' = BX$ are conjugated?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the eigenvalues ​​are negative, we have that the equilibrium points are the way to sink thus suggests that they are conjugated.

Comment: The flows are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

Comment: The flows are homeomorphic if $\phi_A(t,h(X_0)) = h(\phi_B(t,X_0))$ conjugated.

Answer (score 0):

As the eigenvalues ​​are negative we always have a real root. Just analyze situations, we fall in case 2 x 2.\
Case 1: \
$\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\mu_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\mu_3 
\end{pmatrix}$
conjugated $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
                               0 & -\lambda_2 & 0 \\
                               0 & 0 & -\lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}$
by a combination term by term trivial.\
Case 2:\
$\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\mu_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}$
conjugated $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
                               0 & -\lambda_2 & 0 \\
                               0 & 0 & -\lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}$ \
or $\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\mu_2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}$
conjugated $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
                               0 & -\lambda_2 & 0 \\
                               0 & 0 & -\lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}$, Jordan block of 2 x 2, or\
 $\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -\mu_2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}$
conjugated $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
                               0 & -\lambda_2 & 0 \\
                               0 & 0 & -\lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}$\
Case 3 \
$\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\mu_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\mu_3
\end{pmatrix}$
conjugated  $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
                               0 & \alpha & \beta \\
                               0 & -\beta & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}$\
there is two more options in case 1, all is reduced in the case of 2 x 2 smart way.